# Modifying / extending existing substrate pallet without cloning full source

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, runtime, tight-coupling

I would like to modify the substrate transaction-payment pallet's CurrencyAdapter without cloning the entire crate into the local pallets.
What's the best practice to provide another implementation while keep all other functionality as is. Tried tight coupling but this only inherits the features that we want to use within new pallet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CurrencyAdapter` is passed as a value for `OnChargeTransaction` in `pallet_transaction_payment::Config`. And `OnChargeTransaction` has a trait bound `OnChargeTransaction`, i.e a type has to implement `OnChargeTransaction` [trait](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs#L354).

To have a different implementation of `OnChargeTransaction`, create a new struct and manually implement the `OnChargeTransaction` trait. You can closely follow the [implementation](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/transaction-payment/src/payment.rs#L81) of the `CurrencyAdapter`:

```rs
/// Your implementation of `CurrencyAdapter`
pub struct CustomCurrencyAdapter<C, OU>(PhantomData<(C, OU)>);

impl<T, C, OU> OnChargeTransaction<T> for CustomCurrencyAdapter<C, OU>
where
...
{
    type LiquidityInfo = Option<NegativeImbalanceOf<C, T>>;
    type Balance = <C as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;

    fn withdraw_fee(
        who: &T::AccountId,
        call: &T::RuntimeCall,
        dispatch_info: &DispatchInfoOf<T::RuntimeCall>,
        fee: Self::Balance,
        tip: Self::Balance,
    ) -> Result<Self::LiquidityInfo, TransactionValidityError> {...}

    fn correct_and_deposit_fee(
        who: &T::AccountId,
        dispatch_info: &DispatchInfoOf<T::RuntimeCall>,
        post_info: &PostDispatchInfoOf<T::RuntimeCall>,
        corrected_fee: Self::Balance,
        tip: Self::Balance,
        already_withdrawn: Self::LiquidityInfo,
    ) -> Result<(), TransactionValidityError> {...}
}


/// runtime.rs
impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
    ...
    type OnChargeTransaction = CustomCurrencyAdapter<Balances, DealWithFees>;
    ...
}
```